# Pass argument to subprocess of powershell, that is itself a flag

Tags: powershell, runas

```
start-process npm -verb runas -args @("install", "-g", "coffee-script")
```

Is this the most straightforward way to pass arguments to a subprocess? It seems quite verbose!

Answer (score 2):

Well, PowerShell is verbose by its nature and it's a good thing - it makes code easier to understand.

Your example could be shortened using aliases and short parameter's names:

```
start npm -verb runas -a 'install', '-g', 'coffee-script'
```

If you don't need `Runas` verb, it could be even more shorter:

```
&'npm' 'install', '-g', 'coffee-script'
```

If you're using PowerShell v3, there is a new language feature that simplifies a lot of this. Instead of having to stuff around with escaping and quoting parameters to dodge the PowerShell parser, you can now use the `--%` operator which tells PowerShell to stop parsing from that point onward until the end of the line:

```
&'npm' --% install -g coffee-script
```

References:

- [PowerShell and external commands done right](https://slai.github.io/posts/powershell-and-external-commands-done-right/)